# TinyMCE Compatibiliy

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-3

I've developed a project during earlier years, which is based on "TinyMCE editor version 3.x".

However, what is available at the moment on TinyMCE website is "TinyMCE editor version 4.x"

Will my project, which is totally based on "TinyMCE editor version 3.x" work well with "TinyMCE editor version 4.x"?

Also, please suggest any minor changes, so that I can avoid developing the entire form afresh.

Whwn I say minor changes, I mean minor changes. Not too much of changes. Generally, what I find is that, it is better to code afresh than doing too many changes

Comment: The TinyMCE [forum](http://community.tinymce.com/forum/viewforum.php) might have some information about this.

Comment: It is ok. 

The issue is solved. 

Infact I could download TinyMCE version 3.5.11 from http://archive.tinymce.com/download/download.php#

Comment: I suspected this might have been your issue.  For future reference, most previous versions of software are usually available for backwards compatibility, you just need to know where to look.

Comment: Could you please show your TinyMCE configuration?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for seems to be the tinymce migration guide:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/migration-guide-from-3.x/